# HeapWalk block enumeration returns address that is not in the heap

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, heap-memory

Background: at my work (industrial CNC machines running Windows XP Embedded) we have a process that locks all of it's memory into physical RAM by using the VirtualAlloc and VirtualLock family of functions.

I know that at this point, locking memory into physical RAM might not be bringing the benefit that it used to (in previous versions of Windows such as NT), but we're up against a deadline, so while we may be able to investigate removing it in the future, at the moment it's a hard requirement.

So, recently I made a change to a dll that this process uses, which in turn brought in more dlls, some of which create their own heaps (in addition to ones already created in other libraries that are loaded by the process).

The basic structure of the code (psuedocode) is:

```
foreach( heap in GetProcessHeaps() )
{
HeapLock(heap)
    if(!HeapValidate(heap)) { error/assert }

    while(HeapWalk(heap, &heap_entry))
    {
        size = GetProcessWorkingSetSize()
        SetProcessWorkingSetSize(size,size)

        VirtualQuery(heap_entry, page_info)

        if( page_info.State != MEM_RESERVE || page_info.State != MEM_COMMIT )
        {
            VirtualAlloc(heap_entry.ptr, heap_entry.data_size, MEM_RESERVE)
        }

        VirtualAlloc(heap_entry.ptr, heap_entry.data_size, MEM_COMMIT)

        if( !HeapValidate(heap, heap_entry.ptr) ) { error/assert }

        VirtualLock(heap_entry.ptr, heap_entry.data_size)
    }

    HeapUnlock(heap)
}
```

So, this is pseudo-code, the implementation is written in C (I have put proper error checking with GetLastError and FormatMessage around each call to a Windows function).

Okay, so the problem is that previously, the size that was being locked was a total of the data block size and the block overhead, but the ptr being used was the ptr to the data in the block, so there were instances where VirtualAlloc and VirtualLock would overlap past the heap into the next heap, and fail with invalid memory access.

After I had fixed that, now I have a single block that fails during the second VirtualAlloc (with MEM_COMMIT) with the same "invalid memory access" error.

The address it given in the 'heap_entry' structure is 0x00b00020. The strange this about this is that according to the SysInternals tool VMMap (which thus far has been accurate down to the byte in helping me diagnose the previous problem) reports that the heap itself goes from 0xA40000 to 0xA50000, but the address returned from the HeapWalk function is 0xb00020, which is completely wrong.

In fact, the last couple of blocks are past the 0xA50000 range:

```
ppi1: LockInMemory: VirtualAlloc: Successfully Commit memory (00a46f50->00a47163|560 bytes) of heap 5 (532 byte block, 28 bytes overhead)
ppi1: LockInMemory: VirtualLock: Successfully Locked memory (00a46f50->00a47163|560 bytes) of heap 5
Heap 5 handle 10747904 start address 00a47188 size 3704 overhead 16 
ppi1: LockInMemory: VirtualAlloc: Successfully Commit memory (00a47188->00a47fff|3720 bytes) of heap 5 (3704 byte block, 16 bytes overhead)
ppi1: LockInMemory: VirtualLock: Successfully Locked memory (00a47188->00a47fff|3720 bytes) of heap 5
Heap 5 handle 10747904 start address 00a48000 size 32768 overhead 0 
ppi1: LockInMemory: VirtualAlloc: Successfully Commit memory (00a48000->00a4ffff|32768 bytes) of heap 5 (32768 byte block, 0 bytes overhead)
ppi1: LockInMemory: VirtualLock: Successfully Locked memory (00a48000->00a4ffff|32768 bytes) of heap 5
Heap 5 handle 10747904 start address 00a60020 size 589856 overhead 0 
ppi1: LockInMemory: VirtualAlloc: Successfully Commit memory (00a60020->00af003f|589856 bytes) of heap 5 (589856 byte block, 0 bytes overhead)
ppi1: LockInMemory: VirtualLock: Successfully Locked memory (00a60020->00af003f|589856 bytes) of heap 5
Heap 5 handle 10747904 start address 00b00020 size 589862 overhead 250 
ppi1: LockInMemory: VirtualAlloc: Failed to Commit memory (00b00020->00b90045|590112 bytes) of heap 5: (Windows Error 487) Attempt to access invalid address. (589862 byte block, 250 bytes overhead, flags: 0x00000004)
```

As you can see, it stays in the 0xA40000 range until it hits the 0xA60000->0xAF0000 range for some reason, then goes to the 0xB00020 address.

I'm pretty confused. This problem persists no matter whether I lock the heaps during the block enumeration or not. And the flag is has set means that the block is allocated.

Well, I'm locking each individually. Maybe I should lock them all at once? This physical memory locking happens only during application initialization.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here? I'm pretty confused and I can't think of another way to get more information.